# Install Boost.Log on Fedora 17

Tags: linux, boost, installation, fedora

I am trying to install Boost.Log on Fedora 17 and already did `yum install boost-*`. All related tutorials, and answers to similar questions involve moving lib/log into boost source directory and executing bootstrap.sh. I cannot find the boost source directory, or the bootstrap.sh file in my system (did `find / -name '*bootstrap.sh' 2> /dev/null`). All I can find is `/usr/share/boost-build/` with lots of jam files in it. Concluding that the yum installation does not contain the source directory and bootstrap.sh, I tried to build it manually but the Boost.Log source files include windows specific headers and I got double confused. Can anyone shed a light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote the following Makefile to compile and install, which does not include files referring to `windows.h`, I believe it works:

```
SRCS= attribute_name.cpp attribute_set.cpp attribute_values_view.cpp \
      code_conversion.cpp core.cpp \
      default_filter_factory.cpp default_sink.cpp event.cpp \
      exceptions.cpp filter_parser.cpp \
      formatter_parser.cpp global_logger_storage.cpp init_from_settings.cpp \
      init_from_stream.cpp light_rw_mutex.cpp named_scope.cpp \
      once_block.cpp parser_utils.cpp process_id.cpp \
      record_ostream.cpp severity_level.cpp syslog_backend.cpp \
      text_file_backend.cpp text_ostream_backend.cpp thread_id.cpp \
      threadsafe_queue.cpp thread_specific.cpp timer.cpp \
      timestamp.cpp trivial.cpp
OBJS=$(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=2
libboost_log.so: $(OBJS)
  g++ -shared $^ -o $@ -lpthread -lboost_system -lboost_thread-mt -lrt -lboost_filesystem
%.o: %.cpp
  g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -fPIC -c $^ -o $@
install:
  cp libboost_log.so /usr/lib
clean: 
  rm *.o
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the main build tool in the current Fedora repo's yum boost-build package is called "bjam" and not "b2" (as implied by the latest documentation).

So, if you can't find b2 use bjam.